# How to sort an array of integers without changing the original array and at the same time avoiding usage of another array for it

Tags: c

Here, Sample output is :

1. Enter the size : 5

   Enter 5 elements
   10 1 3 8 -1

   After sorting: -1 1 3 8 10

   Original array values 10 1 3 8 -1

**Template code to be used is :**

```
void print_sort(int [], int);

int main()
{
    
   int size, iter;
    
    printf("Enter the size of the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    int arr[size];
    
    printf("Enter the %d elements\n", size);
    for (iter = 0; iter < size; iter++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[iter]);
    }
    
    print_sort(arr, size);
}
```

*I tried solving the problem by multiple ways but couldn't solve it without using an extra array. Looking forward for an assistance or hint of how to solve it without manipulating  the original array and also without using an extra array.*

Comment: Hint: The output stream is almost like an array that can be written to, outputting the lowest values to highest values... The 'print' happens inside your function, using only two variables...

Comment: The requirements are not clear. Where will you store the sorted array? If you don't want to modify the original one, and you don't want to use another one, how can you make any use of the sorted array? If you want to only *display* it, then @Fe2O3 gave you a good hint, but I miss the point of the use case.

Comment: @Fra93 "Use case"? Perhaps processing (and discarding) items that have been gathered-up during "downtime" and assigned a priority somehow. Don't want to see them again, but want the "batch of them" dealt with in priority order (in this case, lowest numbers first). Happens all the time... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 so in your example the input array would be the objects with their priority, unsorted. And you want to sort them in order, meaning you select them from the the lowest/highest and go on selecting one at a time, and making some decisions based on this? Fine, good example, but OP has not specified how they want the output.

Comment: @Fra93 OP wrote "After sorting...".... VERY misleading, if one cannot change original and cannot use a 2nd array... "After" should really say, "Listed here in ascending order" and values are output in ascending order.... Yes, life isn't always what it appears to be... `:)` (That 'clue' would make the challenge too easy, don't you think?)

Comment: @Fe2O3 yes I agree completely with you! Let's wait some clarification from OP!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

void print_sort(int arr[], int len) {
    int current_value = INT_MIN;
    int numbers_remaining = len;
    while (numbers_remaining > 0) {
        int next_value = INT_MAX;
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == current_value) {
                printf("%d ", arr[j]);
                numbers_remaining--;
            }
            else if (arr[j] > current_value && arr[j] < next_value) {
                next_value = arr[j];
            }
        }
        current_value = next_value;
    }
}

int main()
{
    
   int size, iter;
    
    printf("Enter the size of the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    int arr[size];
    
    printf("Enter the %d elements: ", size);
    for (iter = 0; iter < size; iter++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[iter]);
    }
    printf("after sorting: ");
    print_sort(arr, size);
    printf("\n");
    printf("original array values: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

EDIT:
If you need an explanation ask me, but try to understand it yourself. This will help you with these kind of problems in the future.

MORE EDITS:
Ok, here is an explanation:
The function `print_sort` will iterate over the loop and print the lowest interger value if it is found. While iterating, it also searches for the next value to print (the smallest number larger than the current). In the next iteration, it prints all occurrences of the new number found.

Let's look at an example: -2 7 1 1
In the first iteration, the state is like this:

```
current_value = INT_MIN
numbers_remaining = 4
output = ""
```

After the first iteration, all occurrences of INT_MIN will be printed (none), but the loop will have detected the next lowest number (-2).

```
current_value = -2
numbers_remaining = 4
output = ""
```

In the next iteration, all occurrences of -2 will be printed out and `current_value` is updated.

```
current_value = 1
numbers_remaining = 3
output = "-2 "
```

Now all occurrences of 1 will be printed out and the next bigger number is 7.

```
current_value = 7
numbers_remaining = 1
output = "-2 1 1 "
```

In the final iteration, no greater value is found and no numbers are remaining.

```
current_value = INT_MAX
numbers_remaining = 0
output = "-2 1 1 7 "
```

Now we are done.

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer. Stack Overlow is intended to be a durable repository of questions and answers. Its answers should provide explanations, not exercises for study.

Comment: Edited it, I hope the explanation is good enought